# my app size not reduced after update to flutter 1.17

Tags: flutter

as flutter team say, in last update change log they make some change to reduce app size

> This release also provides a considerable app size improvement due to
>   several fixes that add up to a big result. For example, the Flutter
>   Gallery sample for Android was 9.6MB at the end of 2019 and is now
>   8.1MB, which is an 18.5% reduction.

and before flutter 1.17 update my app size was 23Mb and now after upgrading to flutter 1.17 my app size is 22Mb
and its not 18.5% reduction

anyone face this issue ? or have any experience to fix this issue ?

Comment: Are you build fat apk or appbundle?

Comment: fat apk `flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64`